# JQuery: Replacing a visible character

Tags: jquery, html

I have a font which works great except for one character: `0` Luckily the `O` is a perfect replacement, so I decided to write a bit of JQuery that would remove all zeros and replace them with capital Os:

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/0/g,'O'));
```

This works great until I have a link on the page with a zero in it, for example:

```
<a href="http://92.21.52.108:9000">Our server</a>
```

This gets changed to:

```
<a href="http://92.21.52.1O8:9OOO">Our server</a>
```

I thought I'd try using `$("body").text` instead, but that totally doesn't work.

How can I solve this particular problem given that I need to keep the font?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JQuery to do this is a very bad idea.

Either update the font to have an improved '0', or use a different font.

Comment: Why is it a very bad idea, may I ask? It seems to work perfectly at the moment apart from that one quirk. Thanks.

Comment: Because there's a better way to fix the underlying problem - the font.  Also, I hate to think of all the 'wasted' cpu cycles on every client's machine looking at your website.  Seriously though - it's just not the right way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

This would work, but I don't know, how performant it is.

```
​$(function() {
    $('body *')
        .contents()
        .filter(function() {
             return( this.nodeType === 3 )
        })
        .each(function() {
             $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/0/g, 'O'))
        })

})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPfDC/

Comment: The problem is that it replaces CSS, too: http://jsfiddle.net/d44MF/ Thanks anyway, I should probably try and fix the font.

Answer (score -1):

Channelling Crockford, you can use a non-jquery walker much like this:

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 3 ) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(/0/g,'O')
    }
});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/b7PtN/